# Error installing mysql-connector-python from command prompt

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am having trouble installing mysql.connector. When I type 'pip install mysql-connector-python' in Command Prompt i get the following error [image]

Comment: This could happen if you're behind a proxy.

Comment: I believe it is, since is a work computer. How can i fix the issue?

Comment: Speak to someone on the networks team on how to bypass it and allow you to connect to pypi.

Comment: I had to download the package manually by going to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ and picking the 64bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use other options, both are the same,

```
pip install pymysql
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector
```